# A word that encompasses both tablets and desktops?

Tags: variables, namespaces, desktop, tablet, nomenclature

For the sake of naming variables in code, I'm looking for a word that encompasses both tablets and laptops/desktops. Or, devices ranging between those sizes (not phone-sized devices).

Any ideas?

Comment: Some phones are bigger than some tablets, though.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
large_device
```

or

```
not_phone
```

These are not really the most elegant choices, but I think that they fairly clear in their intention.

Can you give more detail as to how you will be using this nomenclature? Is it a prefix? Is it prepended to reasonably short variable names or to long ones?